# Php $_GET issue

Tags: php, arrays, printing, foreach, get

```
foreach ($_GET as $field => $label)
{
   $datarray[]=$_GET[$field];
   echo "$_GET[$field]";
   echo "<br>";
}
print_r($datarray);
```

---

This is the output I am getting. I see the data is there in datarray but when
I `echo $_GET[$field]`

I only get "Array"

But `print_r($datarray)` prints all the data. Any idea how I pull those values?

### OUTPUT

```
Array ( 
        [0] => Array ( 
                 [0] => Grade1 
                 [1] => ln 
                 [2] => North America 
                 [3] => yuiyyu 
                 [4] => iuy 
                 [5] => uiyui 
                 [6] => yui 
                 [7] => uiy 
                 [8] => 0:0:5 
                 ) 
)
```

Comment: Please edit the title of this question to be more descriptive.

Comment: Format better your question, so people understand it better and provide faster answers. Use Markdown or even the buttons over the edit field.

Comment: I think we can understand more if you show us the link which gives such strange $_GET

Comment: It would also be helpful to include the actual URL query you are trying to read via $_GET.

Comment: here is the link let me know if that helps

http://hofstrateach.org/Roberto/story_1.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: When I completed your test, here was the final URL:

http://hofstrateach.org/Roberto/process.php?keys=Grade1&keys=Nathan&keys=North%20America&keys=5&keys=3&keys=no&keys=foo&keys=blat&keys=0%3A0%3A24

This is probably a malformed URL. When you pass duplicate keys in a query, PHP makes them an array. The above URL should probably be something like:

http://hofstrateach.org/Roberto/process.php?grade=Grade1&schoolname=Nathan&region=North%20America&answer[]=5&answer[]=3&answer[]=no&answer[]=foo&answer[]=blat&time=0%3A0%3A24

This will create individual entries for most of the fields, and make $_GET['answer'] be an array of the answers provided by the user.

Bottom line: fix your Flash file.

Comment: PHP only makes keys into an array when they have [] at the end; otherwise it just overwrites the duplicate key with the last specified value.

Answer (score 1):

Use `var_export($_GET)` to more easily see what kind of array you are getting.

From the output of your script I can see that you have multiple nested arrays. It seems to be something like:

```
$_GET = array( array( array("Grade1", "ln", "North America", "yuiyyu", "iuy", "uiyui", "yui","uiy","0:0:5")))
```

so to get those variables out you need something like:

```
echo $_GET[0][0][0]; // => "Grade1"
```

Comment: he doesn't have nested arrays; the first Array is the output of echo "$_GET[$field]", the second is the output of print_r($datarray);

Answer (score 0):

Use `<pre>` tags before `print_r`, then you will have a tree printed (or just look at the source. From this point you will have a clear understanding of how your array is and will be able to pull the value you want.

I suggest further reading on [`$_GET`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.external.php) variable and [arrays](http://www.php.net/types.array), for a better understanding of its values

Comment: this is what i get 
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/public_html/process.php on line 27

Answer (score 0):

calling echo on an array will always output "Array".
print_r (from the PHP manual) prints human-readable information about a variable.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
foreach ($_GET as $field => $label)
{
    $datarray[]=$_GET[$field];

    echo $_GET[$field]; // you don't really need quotes

    echo "With quotes: {$_GET[$field]}"; // but if you want to use them

    echo $field; // this is really the same thing as echo $_GET[$field], so

    if($label == $_GET[$field]) {
         echo "Should always be true<br>";
    }
    echo "<br>";
}
print_r($datarray);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's printing just "Array" because when you say

```
 echo "$_GET[$field]";
```

PHP can't know that you mean `$_GET` element `$field`, it sees it as you wanting to print variable `$_GET`. So, it tries to print it, and of course it's an Array, so that's what you get. Generally, when you want to echo an array element, you'd do it like this:

```
echo "The foo element of get is: {$_GET['foo']}";
```

The curly brackets tell PHP that the whole thing is a variable that needs to be interpreted; otherwise it will assume the variable name is `$_GET` by itself.

In your case though you don't need that, what you need is:

```
foreach ($_GET as $field => $label)
{
    $datarray[] = $label;
}
```

and if you want to print it, just do

```
echo $label; // or $_GET[$field], but that's kind of pointless.
```

The problem was not with your flash file, change it back to how it was; you know it was correct because your $dataarray variable contained all the data. Why do you want to extract data from `$_GET` into another array anyway?

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps the GET variables are arrays themselves? i.e. http://site.com?var[]=1&var[]=2

Answer (score -1):

It looks like your GET argument is itself an array. It would be helpful to have the input as well as the output.