# How to sort an array by keys in an ascending direction?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, query-string

here is the input  i am getting from my flash file

process.php?Q2=898&Aa=Grade1&Tim=0%3A0%3A12&Q1=908&Bb=lkj&Q4=jhj&Q3=08&Cc=North%20America&Q0=1

and in php i use this code
foreach ($_GET as $field => $label)
{
    $datarray[]=$_GET[$field];

```
echo  "$field :";
echo $_GET[$field];;
echo "<br>";
```

i get this out put

Q2 :898
Aa :Grade1
Tim :0:0:12
Q1 :908
Bb :lkj
Q4 :jhj
Q3 :08
Cc :North America
Q0 :1

now my question is how do i sort it alphabaticaly so it should look like this 
Aa :Grade1
Bb :lkj
Cc :North America
Q0 :1
Q1 :908

and so on....before i can insert it into the DB

Comment: I get the impression someone or someones is working on homework
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/83953/php-get-issue

Comment: Your code is filled with XSS vulnerabilities and should not be used in any production environment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
ksort($_GET);
```

This should [ksort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ksort.php) the `$_GET` array by it's keys. [krsort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.krsort.php) for reverse order.

Comment: `ksort()` will indeed do the job, but it is not advisable to modify POST/GET variables, even if it is only to re-order them. A workaround would be `$get = $_GET;` then manipulate the custom array instead.

Answer (score 1):

what you're looking for is [ksort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ksort.php). Dig the PHP manual! ;)

Comment: Posting a hurried link to the documentation perfectly represents how FGITW answers were bad for Stack Overflow and its researchers during the early years.  This answer lacks generosity.

Answer (score 0):

To get a natural sort by key:

```
function knatsort(&$karr){
    $kkeyarr = array_keys($karr);
    natsort($kkeyarr);
    $ksortedarr = array();
    foreach($kkeyarr as $kcurrkey){
        $ksortedarr[$kcurrkey] = $karr[$kcurrkey];
    }
    $karr = $ksortedarr;
    return true;
}
```

*Thanks, PHP Manual!*

```
foreach ($_GET as $key => $value) {
 echo $key.' - '.$value.'<br/>';
}
```